# Better way to route and create View

Tags: php, laravel

I'm pretty new to laravel, and from what I've seen in laravel MVC application, most tutorial with use the controllers to return the view via `View::make('[PATH]')` so the typical scenario will go like this:
**app/routes.php**

```
    Route::get('search', array(
        'uses' => 'SearchController@newSearch',
        'as' => 'search.index'
    ));
    Route::get('search_result', array(
        'uses' => 'SearchController@runSearch',
        '
      ));
```

**app/controllers/SearchControllers.php**

```
    public function newSearch()
    {
        return View::make('search');
    }

    public function runSearch()
    {
        //validate and query search

        return View::make('search')
            ->with('result',$result);
    }
```

Which is all good, except that if later on we decided to restructure the view and place the `search.php` in `web/search.php` for example along with other related view, wouldn't we ended up having to trace all the controllers to update the path to the view?

Instead, is there any cons if I were to make **route.php** as the 'View Factory' instead like this:

```
    Route::get('search',  array('as' => 'search.index', function()
    {
        return View::make('search');
    }));
    Route::get('search_query', array(
        'uses' => 'SearchController@runSearch'
    ));
    Route::get('search_result',  array('as' => 'search.result', function()
    {
        return View::make('search')
            ->with('result',Session::get('result'));
    }));
```

Which will still works, though an extra route is needed to make the view, but we'll only need to trace and update the **route.php** if we need to restructure or change the name of the views.

So will there be any issues writing the route this way with the controllers? or is there other better way to abstract the view path away from the controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously `routes.php` should only every contain information regarding routing. It shouldn't ever contain any business login, this is for the controller. So as your routes currently are I would say that's fine, but if you ever need to add some business logic to your `search_result` route then you need to move it to the controller and modify your routes. I think it is better presented in the controller than in `routes.php`.

Depending on what functionality you are intending to achieve, you could also use [resourceful controllers & routing](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers).

Comment: Well in the example I didn't attach any codes for the revised controller, but yes I wouldn't do any business logic processing at the routes, coz that's what the controller are for, unless you're referring to the attached parameter (result) as a business logic. I get that is how the common practice of writing MVC app, but I'm just wondering in this case, if there's better way to return View, except to write a RESTful controllers.

Comment: @har2vey I'm saying that what you have at the moment I would say is acceptable, but anything more than just a single return should probably be in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You could always create a property in your class for storing the name of the view, and calling that property whenever you want to create the view.